# Event Webpart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

How to create event based webparts in SharePoint 2013 that covers - 
Events – a list of upcoming events with link to the event collection?

Comment: add a calendar app?

Comment: Eric, any other option